# When are TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap sorted?

Tags: java

I have a Map for which I provide a key class for which I've implemented a comparitor.  The comparitor is partly time-based, so the order may change as time marches on.  The question is:  when is the comparison between objects done, at insertion time into the map or at iterator creation time?

Comment: Make your keys immutable. It is done at insertion time and assigned a location in memory.

Comment: At insertion time. But you can easily check it yourself by examining code of those classes. And in comparator is time-based it may cause the issue when you will not be able to get elements from that `TreeMap` by key

Answer (score 4):

The tree is built on insert.

Also, be aware of the following warning in the javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. **The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of a [key] object is changed** in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

So, the compare method should be stable, i.e. should not change because of the progression of time.

Any time a key changes, it must be removed before the change, and re-added after the change.